# Xamarin Studio Sign And Distribute

Tags: android, xamarin

I just can't get passed the "Select Android Distribution Channel" page in the Sign and Distribute dialog wizard in Xamarin Studio. This is just for one project and there are no compilation errors when release compiling the android application. I expect to be able to pick the signing certificate but the next button does absolutely nothing on first click. The second click just closes the dialog altogether. No error message, no nothing, just refuses to go to next step.

Anyone else facing the same problem and possibly have found a solution?

Comment: I found the problem. A "-" character in the package code causes this behaviour. Everything works fine, except the Sign and Distribute wizard.

Comment: In the future, you should be able to grab your IDE logs via `Help -> Open Log Directory` and there should be an Android/MonoDroid log that should indicate the failure a bit more gracefully.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you Jon!